# Exposed filters doesn't work

Tags: 7, views

I have recently come to begin to work on a site built by someone else, so I have no idea of what specifics may have been done when building this site I am referring to. At the moment, I'm trying to revamp the structure (as well as the look to play around with it in sections), and came across an interesting problem.

In the view, I have three exposed filters: 1) Object ID 2) Title 3) Keywords (from the Search:Search Terms filter).

Now when I type in the Title filter, everything works as expected. And when I type in Keywords filter for something that would be somewhere besides the Title, that works as well, with the exception of dates and numbers that aren't in the Title Field.

You can find this page here http://history.arvadahistory.org/photographs1

You will notice that each content type has a picture, then a blue title, then a black string of letters and numbers. An example being this: HF.00668

Now, when I type this (HF.00668) into the Object ID filter, I get absolutely nothing, but when I go to type this in the overall site search, the proper content pops up.

So why would my filters be acting like this? And is there any way to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check query of view when you providing HF.00668 value in Object ID.

SQL query of views can be enable from views settings page with name of **Show the SQL query**. 
[image]

You can also check operator value in exposed field settings.

[image]